# How to set a parameter in partition-by expression to the row value and not to the set aggregated value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition-by

I'm trying to use this mathematical formula in my sql query to calculate the EAM

EAM = 1/n * sum(abs(xi - avg(x)))

xi: is my value for the row in the set of each month.
        n: is equal to 1, 2 or 3 (depending on the existence of the last 3 previous months)

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Test;

CREATE TABLE Test (
[Product] varchar(10),
Year int NULL,
Quarter int NULL, 
Month int NULL,
Value float NULL,
)

INSERT INTO Test

Values ('P1', 2002, 1,  1,  99.54),
 ('P2', 2002,   1,  1,  69.02),
 ('P3', 2002,   1,  1,  94.96),
 ('P4', 2002,   2,  1,  49.54),
 ('P1', 2002,   2,  2,  64.98),
 ('P2', 2002,   2,  2,  10.00),
 ('P3', 2002,   3,  2,  74.81),
 ('P1', 2002,   3,  3,  55.12),
 ('P2', 2002,   3,  3,  95.66),
 ('P3', 2002    ,4  ,3, 43.69),
 ('P1', 2002    ,4  ,4, 83.33),
 ('P2', 2002    ,4  ,4, 33.16)

select [Product]
     , [Year]
     , [Month]
     , [Value]
     , n
     , avg_yi
     , EAM as 'EAM_CT'
from (
         select [Product]
              , [Year]
              , [Month]
              , [Value]
              , n                                                                                                             as 'n'
              , avg_yi                                                                                                        as 'avg_yi'
              , 1 / CONVERT(float, n) * sum(abs(Value - avg_yi))
                                            OVER (PARTITION BY [Product],[Year] ORDER BY Product,[Year] ASC ROWS 2 PRECEDING) as 'EAM'

         from (
                  select [Product]
                       , [Year]
                       , [Month]
                       , [Value]
                       , round(avg([Value])
                                   OVER (PARTITION BY [Product],[Year] ORDER BY [Product],[Year] ASC ROWS 2 PRECEDING),
                               2)                                                                                  as 'avg_yi'
                       , count([Month])
                               OVER (PARTITION BY [Product],[Year] ORDER BY [Product],[Year] ASC ROWS 2 PRECEDING) as 'n'

                  from [GlassFloor_Data].[dbo].[Test] as source_data ` enter code here `
              ) as volatilite
     ) as final_parameters
```

The problem is the average needs to be the same for the last 3 months if they exists or the last 1 or 2 months, 
       if the number of previous months is less than 3. but actually, the used average is that of each row.
 [image: Actual and expected results]

Comment: Please try to format your code and add your input/desired output.

Comment: Also, please try to have a minimal example. (It would be quite difficult for another SQL jockey to reproduce your entire table and populate with data. Could you just select the needed fields?)

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi, Thank you I just added the dataset and a screenshot for actual and expected results

Comment: @Axil can you share the structure of your table Test ?

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi I added the script to create the Test table

Comment: @rajah9 Thank you, i added some details!